# Spark RDD sortByKey triggering a new job

Tags: apache-spark

I have tested sortByKey method with the following code and I have observed that is triggering a new job when is called. I could  find this in the neither in API nor in the code. Is this an indented behavior? For example, the RDD zipWithIndex method API specifies that will trigger a new job. But what about sortByKey?

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))
val l =sc.parallelize(List((5,'c'),(2,'d'),(1,'a'),(7,'e')), 3)

l.sortByKey()
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean pointed out in https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg27005.html, 
"[...]sortByKey actually runs a job
to assess the distribution of the data (see JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1021)".
 I hope that this help others when debugging the number of jobs and stages of an aplications.

Comment: Is this resolved now?

Comment: In the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1021, it is marked as resolved with the Status "Won't fixed"